# Can the IntelliSense of SQL Server Management Studio do this?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, intellisense, ssms

*I am using 2008 R2.*

Intellisense is great, I love it. But I have a lot of tables and 6 different (pretty long) prefixes for the tables. Can I somehow make the intellisense to ignore the table prefixes?

Example tablenames:

- ABCDEF_Blue
- ABCDEF_Green
- QWERTY_Red
- QWERTY_Yellow

In this example I would like to get the name of the table without the need to write the prefix down all the time. So it would look like I type `select * from Blue` or `select * from Red`

Different explanation: I would like the intellisense to use:

```
like '%blue%'
```

instead of

```
like 'blue%'
```

I don't think there is any chance, but still, I am hoping :)

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, you can't do that.
However you can call your tables with an alias in your requests and write something like

```
SELECT *
FROM ABCDEF_Blue b
WHERE b.YourField = YourValue
```

Comment: i know this, but i wish something like this existed for the "before the WHERE" part

Answer (score 1):

Try using [synonyms](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/01/07/sql-server-2005-introduction-and-explanation-to-synonym-helpful-t-sql-feature-for-developer/)...

syntax to create a synonym:

```
USE AdventureWorks;
GO
CREATE SYNONYM MyLocation
FOR AdventureWorks.Production.Location;
GO
```

usage sample:

```
USE AdventureWorks;
GO
SELECT TOP 5 *
FROM MyLocation;
GO
```

Comment: interesting idea. i never used synonyms. i tried it, but the intellisense is not bringing them up :(

Comment: Hum, you're right. The default intellisense does not seem to support synonyms... You can try other intellisense plugins for the sql management studio, however, like [SQL Prompt](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-prompt/) which has full synonym support...